# Windows Server 2003 DNS Forward Lookup Fails Reverse Look Up Succeeds

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration, domain-name-system

I really don't understand why I'm experiencing so much trouble for just creating a simple dns entry for myself. I have a Windows 2003 Server that is a Domain Controller and the DNS Server. This server has 2 ips 192...10 and 192...6. There are Host (A) records setup for 192...10 using confusing.domain.com which correctly resolves to 192...10.

When I try to create an Alias (CNAME) record that points to the FQDN of confusing.domain.com nothing occurs.

If I create an Host (A) record for 192...6 while inside the DNS server I can run

nslookup 192...6 and it will return simpleName.domain.com

however if I nslookup simpleName.domain.com once again it resolves to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `ipconfig /flushdns`. I've seen that fix alot of weird DNS issues.

Comment: 192 is a private IP anyway. No harm in posting the actual full internal address for the most concise answer.

Comment: The first 3 octets are all the same, I thought it would be easier to read not having an extra 10 octects of numbers in my post that offer no meaning.

Comment: FlushDNS seemed to work it's picking up the forward lookup now and I can actually use it, thanks!

Comment: @Chris Marisic: Glad it worked for you. Even though they are all the same ... when you are used to seeing 192.168.1.1 formatting at least for me the 192...1 just makes it harder to read.